# How to distribute FDSN to other users or machines?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I am using a File DSN to connect to a SQL Server database in a linked tables project with MS Access as front end.

When I open the created `.dsn` file, it looks like this:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
UID=XXX
DATABASE=XXXX
WSID=XXXXXX
APP=Microsoft Office 2010
Trusted_Connection=Yes
SERVER=XXXX,XXX
Description=XXX
```

Here, it is showing my workstation's host name and my user id as I have created the DSN

If I want to share the app along with DSN , do I have to change any details in the DSN file ?

What is procedure to be followed to distribute this FDSN to multiple machines? Or simply sharing the file would suffice

We prefer to avoid System DSN as it causes difficulty in deploying the app to multiple users in production

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the DSN and use DSN-less connections. Here are some links
http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1491011/ODBC-DSN-Less-Connection-Tutorial.htm

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/147875/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0